# Background image of Div not appearing

Tags: css, html, background-image, image

I am putting an image within a div which has a background image too. But only the image itself is appearing, the background image of the parent div is not appearing.

My code:

```
  <div id="proceedbody" style="background: url(http://www.asifsinan.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/please-proceed-image.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; line-width:810px; line-height: 718px;"><img id="proceed" style="position: absolute; top:200; left:350;" src="http://www.asifsinan.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/please-proceed-matter.png"></div>
```

Comment: Need the parent div code as well.

Comment: Technically speaking, there should be no parent div b/c proceedbody is an id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with the code, but the one that prevents the background from showing is `position: absolute`. That way, the `img` element is taken out of the normal flow of the document, leaving nothing inside the `div`, so its height will be zero.

However, if you set dimensions explicitly for the `div`, then you can have the `img` absolutely positioned (though it would probably be better, more robust, to set `position: relative` on the `div`, so that `img` “absolute positioning” will be relative to the `div`). For dimensioning, use the `height` and `width` properties.

The settings `top:200; left:350` are ignored by conforming browsers. Use `top:200px; left:350px` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="proceedbody" style="width:810px; height:718px; background: url(http://www.asifsinan.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/please-proceed-image.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;">
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using line-height and line-width instead of width and height in your inline styling of the div...

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a height (and width) to the outer div or it'll be only as high as the image is. Because the image in img-tag is semitransparent in its borders and web cannot show semitransparence, the full outer div is covered by the image.

**edit:** set your inner image as background-image to an inner div could be a better way:

```
#proceedbody{
  background: url(http://www.asifsinan.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/please-proceed-image.jpg);
  height: 810px;
}

#inside{
  background: url(http://www.asifsinan.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/please-proceed-matter.png) no-repeat left top transparent;
  height: 276px;
}

    <div id="proceedbody">
    <div id="inside"></div>​
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change "line-width" and "line-height" to "height" and "width" and also add: `background-size:100% 100%;` to #proceedbody

```
<div id="proceedbody" style="background: url(http://www.asifsinan.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/please-proceed-image.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; width:810px; height: 718px; background-size:100% 100%;"><img id="proceed" style="position: absolute; top:200; left:350;" src="http://www.asifsinan.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/please-proceed-matter.png"></div>
```

Link to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/justinc535/cSrQL/